# Open Excel Data File and Plot Data using Tkinter Button

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I am using Pandas to process Excel files with data. My goal is to be able to use a GUI to select the data file from a certain location and plot the data. I am using the code below. I can plot the data making some minor modifications but the button is rendered useless.

Currently, the code is doing the following :
1) Opens the file location without clicking the button
2) plots the required data but doesn't quit

How can I :
1) Click the button to open the Data file from a certain location (I am being able to do that but when I add code to plot the data, everything gets messed up).
2) Without using app.destroy(), how can I kill the button to be able to move on to the next steps?
I am new to Python, so, any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code is below :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter
from Char_Data import *
def open_file():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    # app.destroy()
    return filepath
app = Tk()
app.title("CHAR DATA PLOTTER")
app.geometry('450x400+200+100')     
Label(app, text = open_file()).pack()
Button(app, text = 'BROWSE', command = open_file, compound = 'left', 
       bg = 'red').pack(fill = 'x')
char_plots.dark_int_sweep_plot(filepath)
plt.savefig('dark_integration_sweep_plot.png')
mainloop()
```